# Extbase extension bootstrapped via a TypoScript object path doesnt cache his action

Tags: caching, plugins, typo3, extbase

I bootstrap a Extbase plugin via a TypoScript object path (USER_INT):

```
lib.pagefiles = USER_INT
lib.pagefiles {
    userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
    pluginName = Pi1
    extensionName = Pagefiles
    controller = PageFiles
    action = list
    view =< plugin.tx_pagefiles.view
    settings =< plugin.tx_pagefiles.settings
}
```

The list action of this extension isnt cached anymore now (I tested it with a print of a timestamp in the controller).

When I load the action via a front-end plugin on the page the extension caching is working correctly.

My `ext_localconf.php`:

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Pi1',
    array(
        'PageFiles' => 'list',
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(

    )
);

?>
```

Does anyone understand whats going on here? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The extension output is not cached, because you used a `USER_INT` object in your TypoScript configuration (`USER_INT` objects are never cached by definition).

Try using a `USER` object instead.